# why all the result equal null?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Employee5(
employee_id NUMBER Generated by default as identity CONSTRAINT b_emp PRIMARY KEY ,
first_name VARCHAR2(50),
last_name VARCHAR2(50),
gender char(1) CONSTRAINT em_g CHECK (gender in ('F' , 'M')),
salary NUMBER CONSTRAINT b_salary CHECK (salary >= 500),
startwork_date VARCHAR2(50),
role_id NUMBER
);

alter table employee5
add CONSTRAINT Role_emp_fk FOREIGN KEY (role_id)  REFERENCES Role5(role_id);

CREATE TABLE Role5(
role_id NUMBER Generated by default as identity CONSTRAINT b_role PRIMARY KEY,
role_name VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

[image]

Comment: Also, don't link to images in your question as most security-minded people won't click on links. Add the information to your question as editable text and provide a bit more information about what you are doing and what result you are expecting - rather than just a 6 word question in the title e.g. what values do you expect, and why, instead of the nulls

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it be `NULL`? That value is as good as **almost** any other.

"Almost" because of

```
alter table employee5 add CONSTRAINT Role_emp_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id)  
  REFERENCES Role5(role_id);
```

which says that `role_id` column value in table `employee5` can be `NULL` or any other value which exists in `role_id` column in `role5` table.

For example, if `role5` table's `role_id` column contains only `role_id = 1`, then the only two valid values in `employee5.role_id` are `NULL` and `1`; if you try to enter anything but, you'll violate foreign key constraint and insert / update would fail.

Furthermore, creating a foreign key constraint doesn't mean that column being constrained will "automagically" get its value - nope, it won't.